# Django using legacy database - OperationalError 'Unknown column'

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using a legacy database(MySQL) in my Django project.

```
DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'mydbpassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }   
}
```

The `syncdb` is runs fine. It doesn't have any errors.  Whenever I run this command,

```
>>> from webservice.models import Users
>>> u = Users.objects.all()
>>> print u
```

I get this error,

```
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'users.id' in 'field list'")
```

Here's my `Users` model from `inspectdb`,

```
class Users(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

What am I missing here?

**Update**

I also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195905/django-operationalerror-1054-unknown-column-xx-in-field-list) but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Read point #1 here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed You have `managed=False` so the `id` column is not created for you

Comment: I see. So that's why I got no result when I run `python manage.py sql webservice'